# SQL join tables without common key

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

New to SQL.  I'm working with AdventureWorks 2012 trying to familiarize myself with SQL server.  Having trouble joining tables that don't share a common key.  Can this be done?

If you're familiar with the AdventureWorks DB I'm trying to return the Name (FirstName, MIddleName, LastName), AddressType, and Address (Combination of AddressLine1, Address Line2, City, State, PostalCode) but that draws from 3 different tables and they don't share any key that can link them together.

Comment: Can you show us the tables, which columns they have?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select t1.firstname, t1.middlename, t1.lastnme,
       t2.addresstype,
       t3.addresslin1, t3.addresslin2, t3.city
from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3;
```

Comment: This will result a t1*t2*t3 values table, i don't think this is a good idea, especially on large tables.

Comment: This is a great answer. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If the two tables does not share any common key, make sure a third table exits that acts as bridge between those two table.

For Example, Table A, and Table C may not have any common key. But in a database, it will be possible to have third table Table B which can able to join with Table A as well as Table C. So using the Table B you can bring together table A and Table C (Logically by the way it is designed).

Answer (score 1):

They may not have a direct key but they are related: You have to learn how to navigate the foreign keys to use the model as it was intended. Have a look at [this diagram of the AdventureWorks](http://merc.tv/img/fig/AdventureWorks2008.gif) data model that ships with SQL 2008. In particular pay attention to the Person section (in a sort of beige colour near the centre).

Person is linked to address by way of BusinessEntity and BusinessEntityAddress therefore your query needs to join these tables to get the info you want. So, your query will look a bit like this:

```
SELECT .pFirstName, p.MiddleName, P.LastName, at.[Name], a.AddressLine1, a.AddressLine2, a.City, a.State, a.PostalCode
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN BusinessEntity be
    ON be.BusinessEntityId = p.BusinessEntityId
INNER JOIN BusinessEntityAddress bea
    ON bea.BusinessEntityId = be.BusinessEntityId
INNER JOIN AddressType at
    ON at.AddressTypeId = bea.AddressTypeId
INNER JOIN Address a
    ON a.AddressId = bea.AddressId
```

I don't have AdventureWorks to hand to test it but that should give you the basic idea. You have to follow the keys otherwise you won't get the data you want or expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
select <fields list> from table1
union all
select <the same fields list> from table2
union all
select <the same fields list> from table3
```

Join them with UNION ALL (or you can use UNION if you should skip duplicates)

Comment: That's not really going to work given that the OP states they are tying to obtain a number of fields which come from different tables and therefore they are likely to have different numbers of fields, and types, coming from each table.